# Network-manager cannot install, dependency issue

Tags: apt, network-manager, dependencies

I accidently installed connmanager, it removed my network-manager and network-manager-gnome. Now I cannot connect to my wifi and ethernet connection. I tried to install network-manager from source (latest version) but it had dependency issues. 
Now when I am connecting internet through usb-modem. 
but still I cannot install network-manager and network-manager-gnome using `apt-get -f`
it shows the following error:

```
apt-get -f install network-manager network-manager-gnome

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

network-manager is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm2.8
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

Suggested packages:
  network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc-gnome
The following packages will be upgraded:
  network-manager-gnome
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 728 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/404 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,214 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depends on libgnome-bluetooth7 (>= 2.27.8); however:
  Package libgnome-bluetooth7 is not installed.

 network-manager-gnome depends on libnm-glib2 (>= 0.8~rc2~git.20091229t135236.302e62d); however:
  Package libnm-glib2 is not installed.

 network-manager-gnome depends on libnm-util1 (>= 0.8~a~git.20090930t162132.866d48b); however:
  Package libnm-util1 is not installed.

 network-manager-gnome depends on libnotify1 (>= 0.4.5); however:
  Package libnotify1 is not installed.

 network-manager-gnome depends on libnotify1-gtk2.10; however:
  Package libnotify1-gtk2.10 is not installed.
 network-manager (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.3) breaks network-manager-gnome (<< 0.8.99) and is installed.
  Version of network-manager-gnome to be configured is 0.8-0ubuntu3.1.

 libnm-gtk0 (0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2) breaks network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9.1.90-0ubuntu2) and is installed.

  Version of network-manager-gnome to be configured is 0.8-0ubuntu3.1.
 gnome-bluetooth (3.2.2-0ubuntu5) breaks network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9.0-3) and is installed.

 Version of network-manager-gnome to be configured is 0.8-0ubuntu3.1.
 libnm-gtk-common (0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2) breaks network-manager-gnome (<< 0.9.1.90-0ubuntu2) and is installed.

  Version of network-manager-gnome to be configured is 0.8-0ubuntu3.1.
dpkg: error processing network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                           Errors were encountered while processing:
 network-manager-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And `ifconfig` shows:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12592 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12592 (12.5 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:100.101.120.10  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:10903035 (10.9 MB)  TX bytes:1972515 (1.9 MB)
```

How can I revert my system back?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add `sudo apt-get check`? And `apt-cache policy network-manager-gnome`

Answer (score 0):

What is dependency for libnotify1 ?
Try sudo apt-get install libnotify1.
Do the same for libgnome-bluetooth7, libnm-glib2, libnm-util1